# How to capture image without showing preview

Tags: android, android-camera

Can anyone help to remove camera preview of open default camera.

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 100);
```

Comment: try this: this might help you!  http://www.41post.com/3794/programming/android-take-a-picture-without-displaying-a-preview

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. There are hundreds, if not thousands, of camera apps that support `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. This includes dozens that are pre-installed ("default camera") on the thousands of different Android device models. Approximately zero of them offer this "feature", because `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` does not include that in its protocol.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible using the default camera using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` as you are using. The API simply doesn't support that.

But if you really want to capture images without a preview, you have to do it yourself or use [this](https://github.com/kevalpatel2106/android-hidden-camera) library. **This library does exactly what you are asking for**. You can also check the code (it's pretty simple) and implement it yourself.

Comment: If your problem is solved using this answer, please consider accepting and upvoting it.